# multiple modals not working. Pure CSS modal, no jquery - changing IDs

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use a css-only modal multiple times on a site. I have changed the Id's to have it display multiple modals but only the first modal in the html code will show up. On click the others dont do anythin gbut change whats in the address bar. What am I missing here?

Also: here is the html code:

```
    <!-- Modal Style Sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-modal.css">


</head>

<body>


       <div class="home-main-section-panel-title" style="bottom:11%;"><a href="#NYCModal">Discounts.</a></div>
       <div class="home-main-section-panel-subtitle"><a href="#discountModal">Tickets • Dining • Retail</a></div>
       <a href="#discountModal"><img class="img" id="fade" src="img/rewards.jpg" alt=""/></a>
       </div>

                                     <div class="home-main-section-panel-title" style="bottom:19.5%;"><a href="#NYCModal">New York.</a></div>
       <div class="home-main-section-panel-subtitle">Theatre  News • B-way Reviews • NYC Discounts</div>
       <a href="#NYCModal"><img class="img" id="fade" src="img/nyc-small.jpg" alt=""/></a>
       </div>

       </div>

        <!-----------------------------------------------modals----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!------------------------------------------------- Discounts Modal --------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<div id="discountModal" class="modalDialog">
   <div class="modal-main-wrapper">
   <div class="modal-controls">
<div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close-modal">x Close</a>
    <div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="back">◄ Back</a>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center"><img src="img/logo.png" width="170" height="48" alt=""/></div>
    </div>

  <div class="modal-wrapper">
<div class="modal-left-wrapper">
<div class="modal-left-top">
    <div class="intro">
    <h1>Theatre:<br>
    Personalized.</h1>
    <h2>Create a FREE account to remove this side bar AND:</h2>
    <h3>
    <br> • Discounts - save on Theatre, dining and retail
    <br> • Customized auditions and job searches based on your best roles and top job skills
    <br> • Students and Teachers - recieve free mentoring from proffesional actors and techs</h3>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-left-bottom">
     <div class="log-in">
       <p>
       Email:<br>
         <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
       </p>
       <p>
         Password:<br>
         <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
       </p>
       <p>
         <input class="btn" type="submit" name="Log-In" id="submit" value="Log-In"><br>
         Dont have an account? Sign-up
       </p>
       <hr>
       Connect With:<br>
       <input class="btn" type="submit" name="Log-In with FB" id="submit" value="Log-In with FB">
       <input class="btn" type="submit" name="Log-In with Google" id="submit" value="Log-In with Google">
     </div>
</div>          
</div>
<!--start modal interior page content-->
<div class="modal-content-right">
<div class="modal-main-wrapper">
    <section id="discount-slider" class="no-margin">
        <div class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#discount-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#discount-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#discount-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(img/slides/nyc.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <div class="carousel-content centered">
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-1">Thespian Rewards</h2>
                                    <p class="animation animated-item-2">Sed mattis enim in nulla blandit tincidunt. Phasellus vel sem convallis, mattis est id, interdum augue. Integer luctus massa in arcu euismod venenatis. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->
                <div class="item" style="background-image: url(img/slides/2.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <div class="carousel-content center centered">
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-1">Save Money - Thespian Rewards</h2>
                                    <p class="animation animated-item-2">Phasellus adipiscing felis a dictum dictum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at ligula risus. </p>
                                    <br>
                                    <a class="btn btn-md animation animated-item-3" href="#">Learn More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->
                <div class="item" style="background-image: url(img/slides/3.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="carousel-content centered">
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-1">Jobs and Auditions</h2>
                                    <p class="animation animated-item-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae euismod lacus. Maecenas in tempor lectus. Nam mattis, odio ut dapibus ornare, libero. </p>
                                    <br>
                                    <a class="btn btn-md animation animated-item-3" href="#">Learn More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->
            </div><!--/.carousel-inner-->
        </div><!--/.carousel-->
        <a class="prev hidden-xs" href="#discount-slider" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="icon-angle-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="next hidden-xs" href="#discount-slider" data-slide="next">
            <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
        </a>
    </section><!--/#discounts-slider-->


<!-- content-->
<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding: 0 !important">
<div class="news-section-one"><div class="section-header"><div class="section-header-left">Featured News</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>




</div>
  </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<!------------------------------------------- end Discounts modal -------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!----------------------------------------- New York Modal -------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<div id="NYCModal" class="modalDialog" style="z-index:999999999">
   <div class="modal-main-wrapper">
   <div class="modal-controls">
<div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close-modal">x Close</a>
    <div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="back">◄ Back</a>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center"><img src="img/logo.png" width="170" height="48" alt=""/></div>
    </div>

  <div class="modal-wrapper">
<div class="modal-left-wrapper">
<div class="modal-left-top">
    <div class="intro">
    <h1>Theatre:<br>
    Personalized.</h1>
    <h2>Create a FREE account to remove this side bar AND:</h2>
    <h3>
    <br> • Discounts - save on Theatre, dining and retail
    <br> • Customized auditions and job searches based on your best roles and top job skills
    <br> • Students and Teachers - recieve free mentoring from proffesional actors and techs</h3>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-left-bottom">
     <div class="log-in">
       <p>
       Email:<br>
         <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
       </p>
       <p>
         Password:<br>
         <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
       </p>
       <p>
         <input class="btn" type="submit" name="Log-In" id="submit" value="Log-In"><br>
         Dont have an account? Sign-up
       </p>
       <hr>
       Connect With:<br>
       <input class="btn" type="submit" name="Log-In with FB" id="submit" value="Log-In with FB">
       <input class="btn" type="submit" name="Log-In with Google" id="submit" value="Log-In with Google">
     </div>
</div>          
</div>
<!--start modal interior page content-->
<div class="modal-content-right">
<div class="modal-main-wrapper">
    <section id="main-slider" class="no-margin">
        <div class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(img/slides/nyc.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <div class="carousel-content centered">
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-1">One Source for Broadway News</h2>
                                    <p class="animation animated-item-2">Sed mattis enim in nulla blandit tincidunt. Phasellus vel sem convallis, mattis est id, interdum augue. Integer luctus massa in arcu euismod venenatis. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->
                <div class="item" style="background-image: url(img/slides/2.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <div class="carousel-content center centered">
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-1">Save Money - Thespian Rewards</h2>
                                    <p class="animation animated-item-2">Phasellus adipiscing felis a dictum dictum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at ligula risus. </p>
                                    <br>
                                    <a class="btn btn-md animation animated-item-3" href="#">Learn More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->
                <div class="item" style="background-image: url(img/slides/3.jpg)">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="carousel-content centered">
                                    <h2 class="animation animated-item-1">Jobs and Auditions</h2>
                                    <p class="animation animated-item-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae euismod lacus. Maecenas in tempor lectus. Nam mattis, odio ut dapibus ornare, libero. </p>
                                    <br>
                                    <a class="btn btn-md animation animated-item-3" href="#">Learn More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/.item-->
            </div><!--/.carousel-inner-->
        </div><!--/.carousel-->
        <a class="prev hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="icon-angle-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="next hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="next">
            <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
        </a>
    </section><!--/#main-slider-->


<!-- content-->
<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding: 0 !important">
<div class="news-section-one"><div class="section-header"><div class="section-header-left">Featured News</div>
</div>
<div class="news-panel-one">
  <img src="http://static.playbill.com/dims4/default/963f390/2147483647/crop/1272x637%2B0%2B0/resize/970x486/quality/90/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.playbill.com%2F42%2F62%2Fbe16d8a54dfcb77c5c5beb018303%2Fscreen-shot-2016-08-31-at-2.17.58%20PM.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""/>
  <div class="news-panel-header">
  <h1>Watch Renee Elise Goldsberry Sing Deleted Hamilton Song at Final #Ham4Ham Concert</h1>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="news-panel-two">
    <img src="https://images.bwwstatic.com/columnpic7/x680D65B537D-9AB9-F646-67EA40A099E17CDD.jpg.pagespeed.ic.1cMkqDeKKt.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""/>
      <div class="news-panel-header">
  <h1>Watch Renee Elise Goldsberry Sing Deleted Hamilton Song at Final #Ham4Ham Concert</h1>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="news-panel-three">  
    <img style="overflow:hidden;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tm-carousel-production/1_top-story_57c08442ad179.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""/>
      <div class="news-panel-header">
  <h1>Watch Renee Elise Goldsberry Sing Deleted Hamilton Song at Final #Ham4Ham Concert</h1>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="news-section-two">
<div class="section-header">
<div class="section-header-left">
  Blogs</div>
</div>
<div style="border: solid black 2px;">
<!-- start RSS Feed code --><script type="text/javascript">document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="' + ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js">\x3C/script>');</script><script type="text/javascript">(function() {var params = {rssmikle_url: "https://newyorktheater.me/feed/",rssmikle_frame_width: "100%",rssmikle_frame_height: "700",frame_height_by_article: "0",rssmikle_target: "_blank",rssmikle_font: "'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial",rssmikle_font_size: "14",rssmikle_border: "off",responsive: "of",rssmikle_css_url: "http://audienceconnections.com/dontuse/css/test.css",text_align: "left",text_align2: "left",corner: "off",scrollbar: "on",autoscroll: "off",scrolldirection: "up",scrollstep: "3",mcspeed: "20",sort: "new",rssmikle_title: "off",rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#0066FF",rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_title_length: "100",rssmikle_item_title_color: "#000000",rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",rssmikle_item_description: "on",item_link: "off",rssmikle_item_description_length: "100",rssmikle_item_description_color: "#666666",rssmikle_item_date: "off",rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M %p",item_description_style: "text+tn",item_thumbnail: "full",item_thumbnail_selection: "auto",article_num: "10",rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",keyword_inc: "",keyword_exc: ""};feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);})();</script><div style="font-size:10px; text-align:center; width:100%;"><a href="" target="_self" style="color:#CCCCCC;">Scroll Down for More</a></div><!--  end  RSS Feedwind code -->
<script>
function htmlspecialchars2($string = "", $maxWordLength = 0){
 return  wordwrap($string , $maxWordLength,"\n", true);
 }
 </script>
</div>
</div>
<div class="news-section-three">
<div class="section-header">
<div class="section-header-left">News</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="news-section-four">
<div class="section-header">
<div class="section-header-left">Video</div>
removed
</div>
</div>

<div class="news-section-five">
<div class="section-header">
<div class="section-header-left">Photo</div>
   REMOVED
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
                             </div>

    </div>
    </div>
<!------------------------------------------------------------- end New York modal ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------modals-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: So how are you using bootstrap without Jquery?

Comment: I see a great big wall of code. It's going to be extremely painful to read all of it. Could you create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: ive stripped the jquery from this example to show less code. The modal however is pure CSS and html.

Comment: code has been simplified to MVCE